# Can I enlarge the menu font size in Delphi 2?

Tags: delphi, fonts, menu

Everything I've found says I can't do this with Delphi 2's TMainMenu but if somebody here has managed it somehow, I'd really like to know the trick. I found code that changes the System menu font size but none that confines the change to only the application. Anyone here know how to do this or do I have to just accept Delphi 2's tiny menu font size that appears on today's large screen monitors? (Moving the app to an upgraded Delphi is not the answer I need ;-)

Comment: Could you explain why you can't (or don't want to) move to a more recent version of Delphi?

Comment: "Delphi 2"? Welcome to 1997. You're going to be amazed at what happens in the next decade and a half. Can't wait for you to get here. One of the things we've gained is "owner drawn menus", which allow you to change the font to whatever you'd like (and you can even add things like bitmaps!!!).

Comment: If you have the time to mock the OP why not use that time to answer the question more helpfully ?  Delphi 2 was quite different from later versions in some key respects and it's quite possible that the OP has an application which relies on the idiosyncracies of that version and cannot justify the cost and effort of upgrading.

Comment: @Phil Can you elaborate on the problem for those that don't have D2 installed any more. A screenshot? Why is the font messed up? How is the VCL implementing menus?

Comment: When you change the system menu font, does your application's menu font change too?

Comment: @Phil According to Sertac, your app's menus are drawn by the system, using the user's preferred menu font. Why do you want to go against the user's desires?

Answer (score 6):

The only way to achieve per application custom menu fonts is with an owner drawn menu.  *Delphi 2* does not support owner drawn menu items directly in the VCL properties of a **TMainMenu** component.  This support was introduced only in *Delphi 4*.

You could still implement an owner drawn menu, but it would involve implementing them using standard Windows API techniques, and handling the required messages on the forms which own the menus involved.  It is not especially difficult but not as straightforward as the event based implementation available in Delphi 4 and later.

You can still use a **TMainMenu** to define your menus but in your application you would then need to programmatically set the owner draw flag on the menu items and handle the resulting messages appropriately.  Doing this, you will need to handle **all** aspects of drawing the menu - you cannot simply set/change the font and leave the system to draw the menu items.  You may also need to provide additional handling for any keyboard shortcuts you have set up.

If this is a viable approach then information on implementing owner drawn menus at the API level [can be found here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647558%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#_win32_Creating_Owner_Drawn_Menu_Items).

Comment: I don't understand this. If the menus aren't owner drawn, surely the system draws them. In which case why are they so darn small? In my experience the VCL has a long history of owner drawing menus when there is no need. It does so with themed Vista menus if there are glyphs to be drawn. But then stuffs it up. If it would just let the system do the work all would be well. I expect that all we need to do with D2 is stoop the VCL owner drawing.

Comment: @David - I can't talk for D2 but D3 menus does not owner draw, they are quite the native menus.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz This makes a lot more sense. The system draws the menus. If the user wants their apps to use larger fonts in the menus, then the user has the means to do so. In other words, the menu font isn't small, the menu font is what the user selected.

Comment: @David, is it possible that the system drawn menus in a non-themed app may be different than the system drawn menus when themed ?  i.e. the user has chosen a particular menu appearance, but the Delphi 2 app is getting special treatment due to its (apparent) age ?  It may even be running in a compatibility mode, if that has an impact on such things ?  I know, I could check this myself but don't have the time right now.  But it seems plausible, after all the Delphi 2 VCL pre-dates OS UI themes by a comfortable margin.

Comment: IIRC system drawn menus are the same in comctl32 v5 and 6.

Comment: And older versions of ComCtl32 ?  Windows 95 shipped with 4.0...  Delphi 2 is perhaps older than you remember.  :)  Does ComCtl32 even get involved in a **TMainMenu** ?

Comment: The system only has one style for menus. The entire question is bogus.